# Function to get mysql results in PHP 7

Tags: mysql, function, php-7

I'm struggling with the following problem. Some years ago, I've written a function to retrieve MYSQL results (multiple rows). Till PHP7, this code worked fine:

```
function MultipleRows($query)
{
    global $dbhost, $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass;
    mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
        or die("Error! Couldn't <b>Connect</b>.");

    mysql_select_db($dbname)
        or die("Error! Couldn't <b>Select database</b>.");

    $result = mysql_query($query)
        or die("Error! Couldn't execute query.");

    if(($result)&&(mysql_num_rows($result)>0))
    {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    mysql_close();
}
```

Now in PHP7, this code doesn't seem to work anymore. After a lot of searching I came up with this as a replacement but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
function MultipleRows($query)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbpass, $dbuser, $dbname); 

    $result = mysqli_fetch_all($mysqli->query($query), MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $result;
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

The function is meant to work with code like this:

```
$res_test = MultipleRows("SELECT id, name FROM table");

if($res_test)
{
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($res_test))
    {
        echo $res['id'].' '.$res['name'];
    }
}
```

It's not a good option to rewrite the 'display code' (last fragment) because in that case I have to rewrite many lines in my website. Who can give me some help in this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql` extension has been dropped from PHP 7, after being deprecated in PHP 5.x.

You could rewrite function `MultipleRows()` using `mysqli` as follows:

```
function MultipleRows($query)
{
    global $dbhost, $dbpass, $dbuser, $dbname;
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname); 
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    if ($result !== FALSE)
      $result = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $mysqli->close();
    return $result;
}
```

A few remarks:

- it is not a good idea to use global variables (`$dbhost`, `$dbuser`, `$dbpass` and `$dbname`)
- this way of handling database queries makes you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your function returns the values I want, but unfortunately not in the way I hoped. I can only display them with a foreach-loop and not a while-loop. Is there a way to change that? And why is it a vulnerable way?

Comment: Uh, I missed the last line of your question - you simply can't use `mysql_fetch_array` in PHP 7. Two solutions come to mind: 1) rewrite the code to use `foreach` instead of `while...mysql_fetch_array`; 2) write a library that will provide you with `mysql_*` functions (it will have to use `PDO` or `mysqli` internally).

Comment: And regarding the vulnerability to SQL injection attacks - when using the function `MultipleRows` you cannot leverage security provided by [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or by `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Okay, then I'll have to rewrite a lot of my code, but it's the best option I guess. Thanks a lot for your answers :)